# Declaration specifiers and declarators

Tags: c, variables, static, declaration, storage-class-specifier

With reference to the question [**Where in a declaration may a storage class specifier be placed?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073952/where-in-a-declaration-may-a-storage-class-specifier-be-placed) I started analyzing the concept of `declaration-specifiers` and `declarators`. Following is the accumulation of my understanding.

#### Declarations

- Generally, the `C` declarations follow the syntax of `declaration-specifiers declarators;`
- `declaration-specifiers` comprises of `type-specifiers` , `storage-class-specifiers` and `type-qualifiers`
- `declarators` can be variables,pointers,functions and arrays etc..

#### Rules that I assume

- `declaration-specifiers` can be specified in any order, as an example
- There cannot be more than a single `storage-class-specifier`
- On the other hand there can be multiple `type-qualifiers`
- `storage-class-specifier` shall not go with the `declarator`

#### Questions

Q1: In the declaration of a constant pointer, I see a mix of `declarator` and `type-qualifier` as below

```
const int *const ptr; //Need justification for the mix of declarator and type-specifier
```

Q2: There can be a pointer to `static int`. Is there a possibility of providing the pointer a `static` storage class? Means the pointer being static.

Comment: When we declare a constant pointer, It looks to me that there is a mixed usage of `declarator` and `declaration-specifier`. *ptr is a `declarator`. Ideally I envision `declaration-specifier` to be a ahead of declarator.But in this case it is `*const ptr`.So is it an exceptional case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I full understand you first question. In terms of C++03 grammar `const` is a `cv-qualifier`. `cv-qualifier` can be present in `decl-specifier-seq` (as a specific kind of `type-specifier`), which is a "common" part of the declaration, as well as in `init-declarator-list`, which is a comma-separated sequence of individual declarators.

The grammar is specifically formulated that a `const` specifier belonging to an individual pointer declarator must *follow* the `*`. A `const` specifier that precedes the first `*` is not considered a part of the individual declarator. This means that in this example

```
int const *a, *b;
```

`const` belongs to the left-hand side: `decl-specifier-seq`, the "common" part of the declaration. I.e. both `a` and `b` are declared as `int const *`. Meanwhile this

```
int *a, const *b;
```

is simply ill-formed and won't compile.

Your second question doesn't look clear to me either. It seems that you got it backwards. You claim that "there can be a pointer to `static int`"? No, there's no way to declare such thing as "pointer to `static int`". You can declare a static pointer to `int` though

```
static int *p;
```

In this case the pointer itself is static, as you wanted it to be.

Comment: Sorry, I **mistook** `static int *p` to be a pointer which points to a static integer

Answer (score 0):

> Q2: There can be a pointer to static int. Is there a possibility of providing the pointer a static storage class? Means the pointer being static.

Well, yes:

```
static T *a;
```

Declare `a` a pointer to `T`. `a` has static storage duration.

Comment: `static` is a storage class specifier and not a type qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the C "declarations" is like this declaration-specifiers declarators;

Here, "declaration-specifiers" comprises of type-specifiers , storage-class-specifiers and type-qualifiers .

"declarators" can be variables,pointers,functions and arrays etc..

errors like :- [Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
This type of errors come ,reason for it is problem in declarations.