# What are declarator specifiers in C language?

Tags: c

What are declarator specifiers and type specifiers in C language?
Can user define or create declarator specifiers or type specifiers? 
I am reading GCC source code, if you can give me some advice, I will be very thankful!
Below is from GCC/c-tree.h

```
/* A kind of type specifier.  Note that this information is currently
   only used to distinguish tag definitions, tag references and typeof
   uses.  */
enum c_typespec_kind {
  /* No typespec.  This appears only in struct c_declspec.  */
  ctsk_none,
  /* A reserved keyword type specifier.  */
  ctsk_resword,
  /* A reference to a tag, previously declared, such as "struct foo".
     This includes where the previous declaration was as a different
     kind of tag, in which case this is only valid if shadowing that
     tag in an inner scope.  */
  ctsk_tagref,
  /* A reference to a tag, not previously declared in a visible
     scope.  */
  ctsk_tagfirstref,
  /* A definition of a tag such as "struct foo { int a; }".  */
  ctsk_tagdef,
  /* A typedef name.  */
  ctsk_typedef,
  /* An ObjC-specific kind of type specifier.  */
  ctsk_objc,
  /* A typeof specifier, or _Atomic ( type-name ).  */
  ctsk_typeof
};
```

Comment: Here is a great post regarding your query. [Declarator and Declaration In C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808932/what-are-declarations-and-declarators-and-how-are-their-types-interpreted-by-the)

Answer (score 5):

**Declaration in C**

---

In C the syntax for a *declaration* is of the form:

```
declaration-specifiers declarator
```

**declarator** are variables or functions or pointers and basically correspond to the name of the object declared.

**specifiers** can be `type specifiers` like `int, unsigned, etc.` or `storage class specifier` like `typedef, extern, static` or `type qualifiers` like `const, volatile, etc.`

For example in the following declaration:

```
typedef long double DBL;
```

We have introduced a new type name **DBL** which is an alias for `long double` and we have:

1. **typedef**: storage class specifier
2. **long double**: type specifier
3. **DBL**: declarator

When you use typedef you are basically aliasing a type specifier with a new name. If you typedef a struct like in the following:

```
typedef struct {
   int a;
   int b;
} mystruct;
```

Then you can specifiy the type of a variable to be **mystruct**, like in the following declaration:

```
mystruct c;
```

---

Related posts:
[What are declarations and declarators and how are their types interpreted by the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808932/what-are-declarations-and-declarators-and-how-are-their-types-interpreted-by-the) and
[How do I use typedef and typedef enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426716/how-do-i-use-typedef-and-typedef-enum-in-c) and
[Declaration specifiers and declarators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092620/declaration-specifiers-and-declarators)

Answer (score 3):

**Declarators** are the **components of a declaration** that specify names of objects or functions. Declarators also specify whether or not the named object is an object, pointer, reference or array. While declarators do not specify the base type, they do modify the type information in the basic type to specify derived types such as pointers, references, and arrays. Applied to functions, the declarator works with the type specifier to fully specify the return type of a function to be an object, pointer, or reference.Reference link [Here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb971bed.aspx)Which is provide more information about Declarators.

Declarators for Pointers

```
int *i; // declarator is *i
int **i; // declarator is **i;
```