# Is long long a type in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration, variable-declaration

I know the title seems quite stupid, but I think it's worth asking.

Take this declaration(or definition, maybe) for example:

```
_Thread_local long volatile static int _Atomic const long unsigned x = 10;
```

I used to consider `long long` as a type, but if it's a type name, how can so many qualifiers be inserted into it?

So I consulted N1570 with this question, only to be more confused. It mentions some terms such as "*type-specifier*" and "*type-qualifier*", and I can't find `long long` in "type specifiers", but isn't `long long` a primitive type in C? There are so many books telling me so!

---

*Clarifying not duplicate:*

Yes, I saw [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30726423/5399734) deals with `long int long`, but this question have something to do with qualifiers, and is in C.

Comment: You can't have `const` and `volatile` at the same time; it's a contradiction in terms.

Comment: That is a pretty amazing variable declaration. Can someone explain how this is parsed? Is the order of qualifiers important? Can you say `long int long unsigned ` instead of `unsigned long long int`?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @Kevin Hmm...Maybe, but when compiling, clang doesn't give me any warning about this.

Comment: @Kevin That's not true. It's legal for a variable to be both `const` and `volatile`, read [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ga.html). Specifically, `volatile` is NOT the opposite of `const`.

Comment: @YuHao: It's legal for a *pointer* to be `const` and `volatile` (or more specifically, for it to point at something with both), but I don't think it's legal for a *variable* to have both.  Certainly it isn't *meaningful*.

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, I forget the source. But this isn't what the original author written. I've changed several qualifier to demonstrate my question better.

Comment: @Kevin: Note that the C11 standard includes: _EXAMPLE 1 An object declared
`extern const volatile int real_time_clock;` may be modifiable by hardware, but cannot be assigned to, incremented, or decremented._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Fair enough; you can have a lot of weirdness when you start getting into embedded situations or variables mapped to hardware.  But it is not something you will just invent *ex nihilo*.

Comment: Legit or not, it is awful. Also the ordering is deprecated, see 6.11.5

Comment: is this used in production?

Comment: @dynamic Someone might be killed by his colleagues if he dare to write such code!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you read the right bits of the standard carefully enough, you find that the monster declaration in the question is valid, even if implausible.

The 'right bits' includes:

> #### 6.2.5 Types
>
> There are five standard signed integer types, designated as `signed char`, `short
>   int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`. (These and other types may be
>   designated in several additional ways, as described in 6.7.2.)
>
> …
>
> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned
>   integer type (designated with the keyword `unsigned`) that uses the same amount of
>   storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements.
>
> #### 6.7.2 Type specifiers
>
> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,
>   and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of
>   type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there
>   is more than one multiset per item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>   intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.
>
> …
>
> - `long long`, `signed long long`, `long long int`, or
>     `signed long long int`
> - `unsigned long long`, or `unsigned long long int`

Other declaration specifiers include storage classes (`static` and `_Thread_local` in the example), and type qualifiers (`volatile` and `_Atomic`).

> #### 6.7 Declarations
>
> 6.7 Declarations
>
> Syntax
>
> *declaration:*
>        *declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;*
>        *static_assert-declaration*
>
> *declaration-specifiers:*
>        *storage-class-specifier
>
>        declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
>
>        type-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
>
>        type-qualifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
>
>        function-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
>
>        alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>*

Also, as noted by [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774918/olaf) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401017/is-long-long-a-type-in-c?noredirect=1#comment58504779_35401017):

> #### 6.11.5 Storage-class specifiers
>
> The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

It is also eccentric to split up the integer type keywords (the type specifier).  A more orthodox version of the declaration would be:

```
static _Thread_local _Atomic const volatile unsigned long long int x = 10;
```

(or it might drop the `int`).

Comment: Translating slightly from spec-ese: the "type" part of a declaration is a list of words, in almost arbitrary order; what matters is how many times each word appears (that's the "multiset" part). If `long` appears twice, `int` appears once or not at all, and the rest is valid (no appearance of other type names, no clashing or invalid specifiers, etc.) you have a `long long int` (signed if `signed` or nothing appeared, unsigned if `unsigned` appeared). Even if a bunch of other stuff is in between.