# Is long a data type or qualifier in C?

Tags: c

I am reading `Programming in C by Stephan G. Kochan`. He states that C has only five data types; `int`, `float`, `double`, `char` and `_Bool`.

What about `long`? Isn't it a builtin type? http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-data-types says `long` is a qualifier to modify the size. If it is a qualifier then it should be only used as a `long int`, and not as a standalone `long`.

And what about `_Bool`? Many Internet tutorials say there is no boolean type in C.

Related:

- *[Is long long a type in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401017/is-long-long-a-type-in-c)*
- *[Is "long long" = "long long int" = "long int long" = "int long long"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726423/is-long-long-long-long-int-long-int-long-int-long-long)*

Comment: `many Internet tutorial says there is not boolean type in C` because `_bool` was added in C99.

Comment: Be careful when browsing random C tutorials on the net. They tend to be full of BS. There is nothing called "sign qualifier" in C, and there has never been. The person who wrote that tutorial simply pulled that term out of their posterior.

Comment: Material on Internet can be trustworthiness but books probably not.

Comment: @GulluButt I wished that was true. There are many C books of horribly poor quality. But it is true that books overall have higher quality than internet blogs.

Comment: @GulluButt: That is the wrong way around.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what is wrong? sorry ?

Comment: there are tons of outdated or horribly incorrect books over there

Comment: tl;dr `long` is both a type (equal to `long int`) but can be a "qualifier"/"modifier" to increase the var size (for `long`, `double` and `_Complex`)

Comment: @vaxquis in `C` qualifiers are `const`, `volatile`, ..... . From my understanding `long` is not a `qualifier` but a `specifier` to extend the size of data types e.g; `long int`, `long double`

Comment: @GulluButt  that's exactly why I said "qualifier" (note the quote marks around it). In your question, you said "long is a quilifier (sic!) to modify the size" - if you define a "qualifier" that way, then `long` **is** a "qualifier", as well as a type keyword.

Comment: What's the publication date for the edition of Kochan's book you are using? The C standard -- the definition of the language -- may well have changed since then.

Comment: Can you please tell on which page number/chapter/section does he state this? Also, which edition?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis it is almost 3 years now. I don't have book anymore. If you are really interested I can try to find.

Comment: Can you please try if you have time? On pg. no. 20 of 4th ed., he states that "The C programming language provides four other data types: `float`, `double`, `char`, and `_Bool`. On pg. no. 433 and 434, he summarizes Basic Data Types where he provides a list of data types and not just the five you mentioned. The same is given in the 3rd ed. I did not find any sentence where he mentions that there are _only_ 5 data types in C.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> He states that C has only five data types; int, float, double, char and _Bool.

That's quite an over-simplification. Maybe intentional, if the book is aimed towards beginners.

If you go through C11 6.2.5 it lists the following distinct data types:

*Character types* (6.2.5/15)

```
char
signed char
unsigned char
```

*Standard signed integer types* (6.2.5/4)

```
signed char
short int
int
long int
long long int
```

*Standard unsigned integer types* (6.2.5/5)

```
_Bool
unsigned char
unsigned short int
unsigned int
unsigned long int
unsigned long long int
```

*Real floating types* (6.2.5/10)

```
float
double
long double
```

*Complex types* (6.2.5/11)

```
float _Complex
double _Complex
long double _Complex
```

*Enumerated type* (6.2.5/16)

```
enum {}
```

*void type* (6.2.5/19) (void type is an incomplete type)

```
void
```

*Derived types* (6.2.5/20)

- Array type
- Structure type
- Union type
- Function type
- Pointer type
- Atomic type

---

Formally the term is *type specifier* 6.7.2:

```
type-specifier:
void
char
short
int
long
float
double
signed
unsigned
_Bool
_Complex
atomic-type-specifier
struct-or-union-specifier
enum-specifier
typedef-name
```

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration
>   specifiers in each declaration, and in the specifier-qualifier list in
>   each struct declaration and type name. Each list of type specifiers
>   shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when
>   there is more than one multiset per item); the type specifiers may
>   occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration
>   specifiers.
>   — void
>   — char
>   — signed char
>   — unsigned char
>   — short, signed short, short int, or signed short int
>   — unsigned short, or unsigned short int
>   — int, signed, or signed int
>   — unsigned, or unsigned int
>   — long, signed long, long int, or signed long int
>   — unsigned long, or unsigned long int
>   — long long, signed long long, long long int, or
>   signed long long int
>   — unsigned long long, or unsigned long long int
>   — float
>   — double
>   — long double
>   — _Bool
>   — float _Complex
>   — double _Complex
>   — long double _Complex
>   — atomic type specifier
>   — struct or union specifier
>   — enum specifier
>   — typedef name

As we can see, `long` is a type specifier. It is not a type qualifier.

Comment: `signed char` and `unsigned char` are listed twice (as char types and integer types).  Why is this? One could read that as if they were different distinct types depending on the context.

Comment: @Zboson Likely to give emphasis that they can be used for either storing characters or for storing numbers, unlike `char`, which can reliably only be used for storing characters (because of its implementation-defined signedness). It is important to understand that the char types are part of the integer types, in order to understand how the various intricate rules of type conversion and type promotion work.

Answer (score 18):

From the C11 draft, section 6.2.5 ("Types)" paragraph 4:

> There are five standard signed integer types, designated as `signed char`,
>   `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`.

How these types are specified in program text is another issue, there are many ways since the syntax is rather lax. For instance, according to 6.7.2 ("Type Specifiers") the following are all valid ways to specify *the same type*:

> `long`, `signed long`, `long int`, or `signed long int`

This says that **`long` by itself is a valid type specifier** for the type `long int`. This was the same in C99 (and, I would *guess*, earlier standards too). So no, it's not a qualifier.

In addition, the above can be intermixed with things like `static`, `volatile`, pointer asterisks, and so on.

I would suggest reading some other book, since it's confusing to read books that use different terminology from the standard. The standard is often refered to when answering questions about C, so it's a good idea to be familiar with it.

Comment: so `long` was never a part of `c` ? Not even in `C99` or `C89`?

Comment: It was, but @unwind decided to quote C11 :)

Comment: I am begginner and at Harward they recommended this book. Do you suggest some other which are up to date? also for beginners? I know other languages but not c so not really a begginner but atleast for `c`.

Comment: "syntax is rather lax" - truer words have never been typed. Years ago after seeing `unsigned` was synonymous to `unsigned int` I was curious whether stand-alone `signed` was consumable similarly. Surprise (6.7.2). Something to keep coworkers on their toes.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm in the habit of using `unsigned` and `signed` alone where I specifically care about the signage, and plain `int` where I don't care, usually because I'm interfacing with some API that uses `int` where it doesn't actually need any numbers below 0... I find this a good combination of clarity and avoiding superfluous typing, fwiw, but dunno whether I'm in a majority here.

Answer (score 0):

In the C programming language, data types are declarations for memory locations or variables that determine the characteristics of the data that may be stored and the methods (operations) of processing that are permitted involving them.

The C language provides basic arithmetic types, such as integer and real number types, and syntax to build array and compound types. Several headers in the C standard library contain definitions of support types, that have additional properties, such as providing storage with an exact size, independent of the implementation.   https://wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types